# GoogleApp Engine authentication using Google ID from Blackberry

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, blackberry

I am developing an app to be hosted on Google App Engine. Users will be able to use their Google IDs to login to the app. The app also has a client counterpart in the form of a Blackberry Application.

My question is - is there a suggested way for my app to collect the user's Google credentials so that I can authenticate it against Google using OpenID semantics? In Android, for example, I can use the Accounts API so that I don't need to explicitly ask the user to enter credentials. What's the way to do this in Blackberry?

I see 2 ways, neither of which is ideal:

1. Write my own form in my native Blackberry app where the user enters Google ID and password, which I then use to obtain the authenticator token and perform the rest of the authentication behind the scenes. But the point is - it is inappropriate to ask a user to trust my app with their Google credentials.
2. Use standard Google Open ID Authentication mechanism - which opens up the web browser and displays Google's Open ID login page. Although this is a one-time thing (after which I can save the authentication token so that future requests to GAE do not require any prompting for credentials), the user experience is still disruptive since it involves opening the browser in addition to my native BB app.

So, what's the suggested way forward?

Answer (score 1):

Using the browser to authenticate is pretty much the only standard way to do this. A number of Android apps do this for OAuth or OpenID endpoints too. Depending on how the Blackberry's protocol handlers work, you should be able to set a continue URL that results in your app being called back by the browser when authentication completes.